# How to copy files with certain permissions to directory

Tags: grep, ls, cp

I'm trying to make a copy of files with read and write permissions for the owner only, and then redirect that file to a directory named `$dirA`. I tried to use this command:

```
cp (ls -l ~| grep -type f-perm 600) $dirA
```

I also tried this:

```
cp -R 'ls -l ~ | grep ^.-rw-/---/---' $dirA
```

But I get this error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'ls -l ~ | grep ^.-rw- --- ---': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think you need the `find` command instead of `ls` and `grep`!

Answer (score 6):

Even if you correct your command substitution, as [Melebius wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/1277103/618353), none of the commands will run, because none of them is correct.

You can use the following `find` command to achieve what you want:

```
find ~ -type f -perm 600 -exec cp {} $dirA \;
```

Note that the above command will recursively search your home directory for files with  `600` permissions. If you want to restrict your search to files in the home directory only, you can add the `-maxdepth 1` parameter before `-type f`.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that `ls -l` doesn't include hidden files. If you want to exclude hidden files, you can add the option `-not -path '*/\.*'` like this: `find ~ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -perm 600 cp {} $dirA \;`

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong syntax for the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). Use `$( )` instead of just `( )` or `` ` `` instead of `'`.

```
cp $(ls -l ~| grep -type f-perm 600) $dirA
```

or

```
cp -R `ls -l ~ | grep ^.-rw-/---/---` $dirA
```

Notes:

- I don’t guarantee there are no further mistakes in your commands.
- [Command substitution using backticks (`` ` ``) is deprecated.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: Even after correcting command substitution, these commands will not work, because they try to use the entire output of ```ls -l``` command (including file sizes, dates etc.) as arguments to ```cp``` command, and not only file names. It would be needed to additionally filter the ```ls -l``` output with ```awk``` before feeding it to ```cp```. The solution using ```find``` in the other answer is much more straightforward.